# BindingSource.count is 1 in .NET4 when data source results view is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I am upgrading a .NET 3.5 app to .NET 4 and have come across this strange behaviour.  We have the following code..

```
    protected static void BindDataGridView(DataGridView grid, Object dataSource)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

        bs.DataSource = dataSource;

        grid.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

When the data source results view is empty (Enumeration yielded no results) - at the point `bs.DataSource = dataSource` - in .NET 3.5 `bs.count=0`.  For some reason when targeting .NET 4 and above bs.count =1!

Can anyone help ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is because didn't mention fully qualified name of your data source

```
   protected static void BindDataGridView(DataGridView grid, Object dataSource)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

        bs.DataSource = dataSource;

        grid.DataSource = bs.DataSource; 

        grid.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, modifying the property `AllowUserToAddRows` of the grid to `false` also works.